# Pig - String extraction using regex

Tags: regex, apache-pig

Iam using **pig** to analyze log files.

My input log file('/user/586376/Pig_C') looks like this.

> **12901890**   \t **rosies blog** \t    **2006-05-15 21:42:19**    \t **1**    \t **http://www.rosie.com**

```
A = load '/user/586376/Pig_C' as (ID:int, query:chararray, time:chararray, rank:int, url:chararray);
```

Here,i want to list the frequently visited sites(***top 3***) during the following time of the day : **10 A.M. to 11 A.M.**

Presently, Iam using STRSPLIT on the time field to extract the required hours.

```
Timesplit = FOREACH A GENERATE url, STRSPLIT(time,' ') as time_split;

B = FOREACH Timesplit GENERATE url, FLATTEN(time_split) as (date,time1); 

C = FOREACH B GENERATE url, STRSPLIT(time1,':') as h;

final = FOREACH C GENERATE url,flatten(h) AS (hour,min,sec);
```

After splitting the time field, Iam using **FILTER** , **GROUP BY** and **COUNT UDF** to find the frequently visited top 3 url's during 10 A.M. and 11 A.M.

**Output:**

```
(http://www.google.com,5)

(http://finance.yahoo.com,2)

(http://www.nada.com,2)
```

But, i feel there must be an easier way to obtain the hours field using PIG UDF's as **regex_extract** and **regex_extract_all** rather than using STRSPLIT. But Iam unable to write a regex to extract required hours from the timestamp given.

Any ideas now to write the regular expression to find the hours from the given timestamp?

EDITED:

Wrote the following regex in pig to extract the hours:

```
data = FOREACH A GENERATE url, FLATTEN(EXTRACT(time,'\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}\\s(\\d{2}):\\d{2}:\\d{2}')) AS (hour:chararray) ;
```

But getting the following error,

Error:

> 2013-08-19 18:20:28,745 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1045: Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.string.RegexExtract as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.

Any suggestions, where iam going wrong???

Comment: So you want a regular expression to match `2006-05-15 21:42:19` and similar timestamps from your log file and specifically extract the hours from that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging by the comments, it appears you are mixing up the arguments of `REGEX_EXTRACT` and `REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL`.  Since you only need to extract one portion, use `REGEX_EXTRACT`, which does not return a tuple, but does require another argument specifying the index:

```
data =
    FOREACH A
    GENERATE
        url,
        REGEX_EXTRACT(time, '\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}\\s(\\d{2}):\\d{2}:\\d{2}', 1)) AS(hour:chararray);
```

Possibly the third argument of `REGEX_EXTRACT` should be 0 instead of 1, I can't remember.  Just try both.

Comment: @WinnieNicklaus....Yes,that was exactly the problem .I was mixing up the arguments of the 2 UDF's and the third argument is **1**.

Comment: If i have to extract all the other parameters like year,day,minutes,seconds et cetra. Should i use REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL. What changes should i make in the existing code???

Comment: Use `REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL`, surround each parameter you want in parentheses, use `FLATTEN` as you had originally, and then provide the schema.  In fact, the code you used originally would have worked just fine if you had used `REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL` instead. (I just think that for extracting a single group, `REGEX_EXTRACT` makes more sense conceptually.)

Answer (score 1):

Your data seems to be well formatted so i guess you can use the following expression to match the timestamps, notice it will only capture the hours in a group. If you need other parts of the timestamps just surround it with the parentheses `( and )`.

```
\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s(\d{2}):\d{2}:\d{2}
```

Comment: Yes Precisely. Could you give the command to be executed in pig using this regex.

Comment: @Ankita I am sorry as I don't know what is pin nor I know its syntax.